# How to do several enumerations type in Fortran?

Tags: enums, fortran

I tried to declare several enumeration types in Fortran.

This funny simple example illustrates well my problem :

```
program Main
  
  enum, bind(c)
    enumerator :: Colors = 0
    enumerator :: Blue = 1
    enumerator :: Red = 2
    enumerator :: Green = 3
  end enum

  enum, bind(c)
    enumerator :: Size = 0
    enumerator :: Small = 1
    enumerator :: Medium = 2
    enumerator :: Large = 3
  end enum
      
  integer(kind(Colors)) :: myColor

  myColor = Green

  if (myColor == Large) then
    write(*,*) 'MyColor is Large'
  end if

end program Main
```

I also tried to enclose this enumeration in a type and many others things but none works.

Here I can compare `Colors` with `Size`. In C, for example, when I declare `color` and a `size` typedef enum, I have no such problem, because the two types are different.

Does it exist a simple solution to have several enumerated type in Fortran?

Otherwise, I imagine to declare several types with one integer member that holds the value and, after, to create interface to overload the operators I need (comparison, affectation and so on). I am not sure that solution is possible and also, I can do it.

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are trying to do with enumerations here? It's not clear to me what you expect to happen in this program or what you'd like to happen instead. Enumerators are integers, and follow all the usual rules of that intrinsic type.

Comment: @francescalus. Increase the program readability, detect programming errors at compilation time and use only allowed values (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#Rationale)

Comment: What errors are you trying to catch, though?  You've defined a named constant `Green` with value 3 and a named constant `Large` with value 3.  `Green==Large` is going to evaluate as true.

Comment: @franscescalus. I understand why I have this output. That is the problem. I can compare Colors with Size. In C, for example, when I declare color and a size typedef enum, I have no such problem, because the two types are different.

Comment: Then hopefully my answer addresses your misunderstanding. If it doesn't, please do ask for clarification.

Comment: @francescalus. I understand the problem. https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Typed+enumerators does not exist in Fortran.

Comment: @francescalus. Just a comment that is not comment and I will remove it. I would like to thank you for your comments and answers to all my questions. My program runs perfectly and everything is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Fortran does not have enumerated types in the sense that you wish to use.<sup>1</sup>

An enumeration in Fortran is a set of enumerators.  The program of the question has two of them.

Enumerators themselves are named (integer) constants of a kind interoperable with C's corresponding enumeration type. They exist for the purposes of C interoperability and not to provide a similar functionality within Fortran.

The enumerators `Green` and `Large` in the question are two named integer constants with value 3 (of some, possibly different kind).  `Green==Large` is a true expression whatever the kind parameters of the constants.

There is no mechanism in Fortran to restrict a variable to values of an enumeration.  The constants could equivalently be declared as

```
integer(kind=enum_kind1) :: Green = 3_enum_kind1
integer(kind=enum_kind2) :: Large = 3_enum_kind2
```

for the appropriate kind values (which are quite likely in this case to be the same: `C_INT`) and the Fortran program would know no difference.

If you wish to use enumerated types in the sense that they exist in C and similar languages, you will have to use a non-intrinsic approach (as intimated in the question).

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the case for the current, 2018, revision of the language. At this time, there is a proposal for the next revision (provisionally 2023) to include enumerated types closer to what is desired here. This specification is given in 7.6.2 of one particular [working draft](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/22/22-007r1.pdf).

Comment: Do you know where I could find a close example of the non-intrinsic approach intimated in the question ? I am able to find one except this one : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/255373/enum-class-in-fortran

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not away of any popular/de-facto standard implementation. This is one of those areas where it's quite easy to do something fairly basic that may meet some requirements, but really very hard to do something that covers many use cases in a robust and clear way.

Comment: I think it is good point out that there is a a new kind of `enumeration` type approved for the following standard, but several members of the Fortran community think that this approved proposal is seriously flawed. https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/flaw-with-typed-enumerators-in-f202x/3429